# Use portable VSCode with portable powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, portability

I have a portable VSCode install on an external USB SSD.
I need it to switch systems a lot and still have a familiar environment.
However, some systems I work on dont have powershell.
So, I have downloaded a portable install to the USB.
I know how to set up this to use it, but it makes problems when e.g. the drive letter changes, because that alters the path.

How do i relative that?
e.g. use a path like:

`{VSCodeDir}\powershell\pwsh.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), there is

> ${execPath} - location of Code.exe

Comment: How would I only get the folder path from that?

Comment: Nevermind, this works: ```${execPath}\\..\\```
Thanks for the help!

Comment: @LightJack05, Does it still work? I can't get it work in VSCodium 1.67.2

Comment: @OldSkull Yeah, still works fine for me.