# How to reference in settings a path to subdirectory within VSCode portable (relative to 'Code.exe')?

Tags: visual-studio-code, portability

I'd appreciate your help.

According to VSCode [Variables Reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference), I was expecting something like this to work:

```
${execPath}\data_cadu
```

Nonetheless, ${execPath} didn't work.

How to set up path to subdirectory within VSCode portable for Windows (relative to 'Code.exe')?

The screenshot below details further the path I'm trying to set within VSCode settings.

Thank you!

[image: subdirectory within VSCode]

Answer (score 2):

In the described context, the path to a subdirectory is related to an extension that wasn't recognizing `${execPath}`. I [contacted the extension developer](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/Favorites.vscode/issues/33), who provided a clarifying answer:

> in this case I simply replace `${execPath}` with the return value of the `process.exePath`.
>
> Thus your desired path should be:
>
> ```
> ${execPath}\..\data_cadu
> ```
>
> Note extra `..` as `exePath` is not the dir but the exe file.

I already tested the path `${execPath}..' with other extensions, which have recognized it.

This reply is also aligned to [another thread about using powershell within VSCode portable subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68880358/use-portable-vscode-with-portable-powershell), who reported that `${execPath}\..\` worked properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How to get that in linux? (using bash)